# Javascript Function Variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, filter, find

Can someone please help me fix this function? It will work if I change the two variables to integers (ie: '987') but if I change them to a character value like 'test' it won't search the array.

I'm new to javascript so excuse me if this is an easy fix. Thank you in advance.

```
var myArray = [{
  'Vendor': '123',
  'Item': '987',
  'ID': '1'
}, {
  'Vendor': '123',
  'Item': '654',
  'ID': '2'
}];

function findById(source, Vendor, Item) {
  return source.filter(function(obj) {
    return +obj.Vendor === +Vendor, +obj.Item === +Item;
  })[0];
}
var vendin = '123';
var prodin = '654';
var result = findById(myArray, vendin, prodin);
console.log(result.ID);
```

The variables in question are `vendin` and `prodin`.

Comment: I'm confused by the comma in your `return` statement. Didn't you mean to use `return +obj.Vendor === +Vendor && +obj.Item === +Item;` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

var myArray = [{'Vendor': '123','Item':'987','ID':'1'},
               {'Vendor': '123','Item':'654','ID':'2'}, {'Vendor': "test",'Item':"test2",'ID':'3'}];

```
function findById(source, Vendor, Item) {

    var x = source.filter(function( obj ) {
        return (obj.Vendor == Vendor && obj.Item == Item);
    })[ 0 ];
    return x;
}

var vendin = "test";
var prodin = "test2";
var result = findById( myArray,vendin,prodin)

console.log(
result.ID
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your return statement is wrong, it is only going to return whatever the last statement results in: `+obj.Item === +Item`, you need to use a logical operator `&&`,`||` between the statements not a comma

```
return +obj.Vendor === +Vendor, +obj.Item === +Item;
```

should be

```
return (+obj.Vendor === +Vendor) && (+obj.Item === +Item);
```

Also remove the `+` if testing strings